# Counting instances of a character in a string

Tags: openedge, progress-4gl

I need to be able to count the instances of a period in a string. (I need to capture the decimal point in a number, but discard the other periods in the name or title.) I know NUM-ENTRIES essentially counts the number of entries *around* that character, but I want to do the opposite. My broader problem is to parse a decimal number out of a string, where occasionally the string has other periods in the string.

What syntax can I use to determine the number of periods in this string? See my pretend "NUM-PERIODDS" pretend Progess function below.

Erin L. Halpin (33.333%)

Mr. Thomas Q. Smith 66.6%

I have an algorith to take everything in front of the "%" sign, then I process through all the numbers, but if I find a second "." then I need to skip that character. (If there are better ways to do my algorithm, would love suggestions on that, too.)

```
//takes in the full joint name and sees if there is a percentage value in it
//then finds whatever is in front of the % sign
IF INDEX (full_name_percentage, "%") GT 0 THEN DO:
        cBeforePercentageStr= 
        SUBSTRING(full_name_percentage,1,INDEX(full_name_percentage,"%") - 1).
        IF LENGTH (cBeforePercentageStr) GT 0 THEN DO:
            //MESSAGE full_name_percentage VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
            cThisChar = "".
            DO iTemp = 1 TO LENGTH(cBeforePercentageStr):
                cThisChar = SUBSTRING(cBeforePercentageStr,iTemp,1).
                IF fnIsNumericOrPeriod(cThisChar) THEN 
                   cPercentage = cPercentage + cThisChar.
            END.
            //need to account for if there are two decimal points
            IF **NUM-PERIODS** (cPercentage, ".") GT 1 THEN DO:
               MESSAGE "cPercentage value " + cPercentage VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
               cPercentage = SUBSTRING(cPercentage,2,LENGTH(cPercentage)).
            END.
            dPercent = TRUNCAT (DECIMAL(cPercentage),2).
     END.
END.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no need for loops. The number of characters in a string is equal to the length of the string minus the length of that same string without those characters.

```
define variable p as integer no-undo.

define variable myString as character no-undo.

myString = 'Erin L. Halpin (33.333%) Mr. Thomas Q. Smith 66.6%'.

p  =  length( myString )
   -  length( replace( myString, '.', '' ) )
   .

message 'there are' p 'periods in the string'.
```

Comment: Clever! I like it.

Answer (score 2):

Golfing on you can also just return the number of entries with "." as delimiter minus one but with a floor of 0.

```
DEFINE VARIABLE i    AS INTEGER   NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE cStr AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.

cStr = 'Erin L. Halpin (33.333%) Mr. Thomas Q. Smith 66.6%'.

i = MAX(NUM-ENTRIES(cStr, ".") - 1,0) .

MESSAGE SUBSTITUTE("There are &1 periods in the string", i) VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
```

Answer (score 1):

I like Stefan's idea (and it's pretty foolproof) but for a bit of code golf fun, you can loop without looping all the characters ...

```
DEFINE VARIABLE str AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE findChr  AS CHARACTER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE cnt AS INTEGER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE pos AS INTEGER NO-UNDO.
DEFINE VARIABLE startPos AS INTEGER NO-UNDO.

str = "Erin L. Halpin (33.333%) Mr. Thomas Q. Smith 66.6%".
findChr = ".".
startPos = 1.
pos = INDEX(str, findChr, startPos).
DO while pos > 0:
   cnt = cnt + 1.
   startpos = pos + 1.
   pos = INDEX(str, findChr, startPos).
eND.

MESSAGE 
cnt
    VIEW-AS ALERT-BOX.
```

Answer (score 0):

This is kind of crude and ugly but it should work just fine:

```
define variable i as integer no-undo.

define variable n as integer no-undo.
define variable p as integer no-undo.

define variable myString as character no-undo.

myString = "Erin L. Halpin (33.333%) Mr. Thomas Q. Smith 66.6%".

n = length( myString ).
do i = 1 to n:
  if substring( myString, i, 1 ) = "." then p = p + 1.
end.

message "there are" p "periods in the string".
```

Comment: Nice, thanks, I can add that as another little parsing function in the repertoire! Messy data needs a lot of clever parsing:-)